# Struggling a bit on the factoring in this induction proof

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-writing, induction

This is a simple problem in a Number Theory book I just purchase.  I've struggled with this for a bit and I thought it may be time to ask for some extra eyes.  I'm just not seeing the next step and I'm not sure why.  So, the problem, prove $\sum_{i=1}^{n} n^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$.  I'm constantly getting stuck at this point $(k+1)\left [ \frac{2k^2+7k+1}{6} \right ]$.  Since I'm likely getting stuck somewhere in the process, here is my work.

\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^{n=k+1} n^2 & =  \frac{(k)(k+1)(2k+1)}{6} + (k + 1)^2 \\
         & =  (k+1) \left [ \frac{k(2k+1)}{6} + (k+1) \right ] \\
         & =  (k+1) \left [ \frac{2k^2 + 7k + 1}{6} \right ] \\
\end{align}

Comment: Your equality is wrong. $\frac{k(2k+1)}{6}+(k+1)=\frac{2k^2+7k+6}{6}$

Comment: Then you can solve for the zeros of the polynomial and use them to factor it.

Comment: @Simon  oh my goodness, how stupid of me.  Thank you.  Yes, I completely missed that simple error.  I failed to completely distribute the 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^{n=k+1} n^2  & =  \sum_{i=1}^{n=k} n^2 + (k + 1)^2 \\
 & =  \frac{(k)(k+1)(2k+1)}{6} + (k + 1)^2 \tag{ind.hyp.}\\
 & =  (k+1) \left [ \frac{k(2k+1)}{6} + (k+1) \right ] \\
 & =  (k+1) \left [ \frac{2k^2 + k}{6} +\frac{6k + 6}{6} \right ] \\
 & =  (k+1) \left [ \frac{2k^2 + 7k + \color{red}{6}}{6} \right ] \\
 & =  \frac 16(k+1)  (k+2)(2k+3) \\
\end{align}and so on.

Comment: Thank you.  I found the proof within minutes of reading this.